# How to close popup window?

Tags: java, android, popup

I have an activity with custom popup window (quickaction style). There are some buttons leading to other activities. I want to close popup after pressing button (about or email button) in this popup (now when I go back popup appears again).

```
public class FirstActivity extends Activity implements OnClickListener {

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

               // some code

    Button quickButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button_quickaction);

    quickButton.setOnClickListener(this);

    final ActionItem about = new ActionItem();
    final ActionItem email = new ActionItem();

    quickButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            QuickAction qa = new QuickAction(v);

            qa.addActionItem(about);
            qa.addActionItem(email);
            qa.setAnimStyle(QuickAction.ANIM_GROW_FROM_RIGHT);

            qa.show();
        }
    });


    about.setTitle("About");
    about.setIcon(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.about));
    about.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            //some code
        }
    });

    email.setTitle("Email");
    email.setIcon(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.email));
    email.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            //some code
        }
    });

}

}
```

Please, help.

---

**Added:**

I need something like this:

```
about.setTitle("About");
    about.setIcon(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.about));
    about.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            qa.dismiss();
        }
    });
```

But `qa` cannot be resolved. Even if I add `final` to `QuickAction qa = new QuickAction(v);`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try `finish()` on button's onClick method.

**updated:**

```
QuickAction qa;
quickButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            qa = new QuickAction(v);

            qa.addActionItem(about);
            qa.addActionItem(email);
            qa.setAnimStyle(QuickAction.ANIM_GROW_FROM_RIGHT);

            qa.show();
        }
    });


    about.setTitle("About");
    about.setIcon(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.about));
    about.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            if(qa.isShowing())
               qa.dismiss();
            //some code
        }
    });

    email.setTitle("Email");
    email.setIcon(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.email));
    email.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            if(qa.isShowing())
               qa.dismiss();
            //some code
        }
    });
```

you can also put  `private QuickAction qa;`  at your activity.

Comment: It's not the solution because after I go back to activity with popup, it (activity with popup) closes.

Comment: you may try with `dismiss()` method.

Comment: Yes, I know that. But look at the question, please. I added what I exactly need to do to make it work.

Comment: `QuickAction qa;` doesn't work but `private` works. Thanks for solution.

Comment: I have one more question. I want to put `if(qa.isShowing()) qa.dismiss();` in method `onRestart`. But `isShowing` is undefined for the type QuickAction. How can I do that? Help, please.

Comment: It is strange b/c i think your QuickAction dialog is inherited from `PopupWindow`. So, `dismiss()` and `isShowing()` may come from `PopupWindow`'s methods too. I may not know well about this.

Comment: see more at: [http://greendroid.cyrilmottier.com/reference/greendroid/widget/QuickActionWidget.html](http://greendroid.cyrilmottier.com/reference/greendroid/widget/QuickActionWidget.html)